Lumen test PHPUnit
Im trying to do a unit test with phpunit in lumen and I need to set up a usecase that uses eloquent's when, but I'm getting an error, where analyzing when it will execute the query in the usecase does not return anything in the model.
This is my usecase :
    public function execute(Request $request) {
        try{
            $access = VerifyPermissionUseCase::execute('et-perferendis', 'view');
            if(!$access) {
                return response()->json(__('general.module_unauthorized'), 400);
            }

            $category = Category::when($request['name'], function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request['name'].'%');
            })->paginate();
            dd('asda');
            $this->registerLog("SearchCategoryUseCase");
            return CategoryResource::collection($category);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Log::error(
                [
                    'local' => 'Error to search category',
                    'error' => basename($e->getFile()) . ' Line : '. $e->getLine() .' | '. $e->getMessage()
                ]
            );
            return response()->json(__('category/messages.search.generic_erro'), 400);
        }
    }

this is my test:
public function testExecuteSuccess()
    {
        // Mock da permissão
        app()->instance(
            VerifyPermissionUseCase::class,
            m::mock(VerifyPermissionUseCase::class, function (m\MockInterface $mock) {
                $mock->shouldReceive('execute')
                    ->with('et-perferendis', 'view')
                    ->andReturn(true);
            })
        );

        // Mock do modelo Category
        app()->instance(
            Category::class,
            m::mock(Category::class, function (m\MockInterface $mock) {
                $queryMock = m::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');

                $mock->shouldReceive('when')
                    ->withArgs(function ($condition, $callback) {
                        return $condition && is_callable($callback);
                    })
                    ->andReturnUsing(function ($condition, $callback) use ($queryMock) {
                        if ($condition) {
                            $callback($queryMock);
                        }
                        return $queryMock;
                    });

                $queryMock->shouldReceive('where')
                    ->with('name', 'LIKE', '%Test Category%')
                    ->andReturnSelf();

                $categories = new LengthAwarePaginator(
                    [(object)['id' => 1, 'name' => 'Category 1']],
                    1, // Total de itens
                    15 // Itens por página
                );

                $queryMock->shouldReceive('paginate')
                    ->once()
                    ->andReturn($categories);
            })
        );

        // Mock da requisição
        $mockRequest = m::mock(Request::class);
        $mockRequest->shouldReceive('toArray')
            ->andReturn(['name' => 'Test Category']);

        // Executa o caso de uso
        $useCase = new SearchCategoryUseCase();
        $result = $useCase->execute($mockRequest);

        // Validações
        $this->assertInstanceOf(\Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection::class, $result);
        $this->assertCount(1, $result->collection);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $result->collection->first()->id);
        $this->assertEquals('Category 1', $result->collection->first()->name);
    }

I searched and couldn't find anything demonstrated on how to mock up the when,
